# Angular variable i set before above function is complete

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I wasnt quite sure what to call this question but here is the issue.

I have the following `$watch`:

```
    $scope.$watch('academyModules', function (newVal) {
    var i = 1;
    var shouldIUpdate = false;
    if ($scope.isSorted) {
        newVal.forEach(function (y) {
            if (y.sort_number != i) {
                shouldIUpdate = true;
            }
            i++;
        });
        if (shouldIUpdate) {
            $scope.rearrangeModules();
        }
    }
}, true);



$scope.rearrangeModules = function () {
    var currentSortNumber = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.academyModules.length; i++) {
        $scope.academyModules[i].sort_number = currentSortNumber;
        if ($scope.academyModules[i].module_id == null) {
            $http({
                url: api.getUrl('updateCourseSortNumber', [$scope.academyModules[i].id, $scope.academyModules[i].sort_number]),
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    academyCourse: $scope.academyCourse
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            });
        }
        else {
            $http({
                url: api.getUrl('updateSortNumber', null),
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    module: $scope.academyModules[i]
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            });
        }
        currentSortNumber++;
    }
}
```

This is used for when my use drag and drops an item in a list.

This `list` is collected from an `$http` request that looks like this:

```
$http.get(api.getUrl('modulesByAcademy', $scope.current_id))
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.academyModules = [];
        if (response != "") {
            response.forEach(function (y) {
                $scope.academyModules.push(y);
            });
        }
        $http.get(api.getUrl('academyCourseByAcademy', $scope.current_id))
            .success(function (response) {
                if (response != "") {
                    response.forEach(function (y) {
                        $scope.academyModules.push(y);
                    });
                    $scope.academyModules.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return a.sort_number > b.sort_number;
                    });
                }
                $scope.isSorted = true;

            });
    });
```

basicly what this does it collect two types of the so called `modules` insert them into a common list and then sort this list.

The reason i have the variable `isSorted` is to make sure that the `watcher` function is not called over and over when the list is being created.

This works fine for lists under 10 (mainly because i think the sorting is fast enough) however for bigger lists (say 20 items) the `isSorted = 1` is called before the list is done generating thus making my system reordering the items in the list in an odd way.

My question is how can i avoid this?

Comment: Your question aside, try to use $q.all instead of calling promise within promise. Atleast it should be suitable for your case. academyCourseByAcademy api is not dependent on the output of modulesByAcademy. I am not sure your about all your use cases but I think you dont need a watcher (for this case). You can move the watcher to a service and call the service after the promise is resolved. Maybe you have not posted all the cases but just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong compare function for your sort, try

```
return a.sort_number - b.sort_number;
```

instead.

Comment: The general contract of a comparator function is three valued:
if (a < b) return -1; (more loosely anything less than zero)
if (a == b) return 0;
if (a > b) return 1; (or anything greater than zero)

the boolean expression a > b is two valued (0 or 1) so it would not return a correct value of -1 for when a < b.

this would result in a peculiar sort ordering.